# Adding css to a form

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I am trying to add CSS to my form but not sure how to do this. The form is created in php and MySQL, in browser it looks like: http://gyazo.com/5d099ead9bd6ea83859a5114b2438748

I need to allign the text and drop downs so they are in the equal throughout and add some spacing. Anyone help with CSS for this?

html currently:

```
  <div class="wrap">
              <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Highdown logo" />
              <h1>Entry form</h1> 
            </div>
```

css currently:

```
.wrap {
                position: relative;
                }
```

The form is produced with this:

```
if ($event_result = $con->query("SELECT Event.Name FROM event")) {  
                echo "<form method =\"POST\" action=\"save.php\"> ";
                            while ($row = $event_result->fetch_assoc()) {               
                            echo $row['Name']. ' ';

                                if ($student_result = $con->query("SELECT Student.Form, Teacher.Form, Student.Forename, Student.Surname, Student_ID " .
                                    "FROM Student, Teacher " .
                                        "WHERE Student.Form = Teacher.Form AND Teacher.Username = '" . $_SESSION['Username'] . "'")) {

                                    if ($student_result->num_rows) {                                                                                
                                                echo "<select name ='". $row['Name']."'>";  
                                                    while ($row1 = $student_result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                                    echo '<option value="" style="display:none;"></option>';
                                                    echo "<option value ='" . $row1['Student_ID'] . "'>" . $row1['Forename'] . ' ' . $row1['Surname'] . "</option>";
                                                }
                                                echo "</select> <br />";                    
                                    }                                                                   
                                }
                            }   
                        echo '<input type="submit" value ="Submit">';
                        echo '<input type="reset" value ="Reset">';

                        echo '<input type="button" value = "Add student" onclick="location.href=\'http://localhost/sportsday/addstudent.php\'">';
                        echo '<input type="button" value = "Delete student">';
                echo "</form>"; 
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
<form>
    <table>
      <tr> //1st Table row
        <td></td> //Table column data
        <td></td> //table column data
      </tr> //1st row ends

      <tr> // 2nd Table row
        <td></td> //Table column data
        <td></td> //table column data
      </tr> //2nd row ends
    </table>
</form>
```

This will give you a better layout of the form.

Comment: will do that, just to confirm, table tags go outside the form tags? and how about the tr and td tags? where would they go within the form

Comment: @cbaker only `<tr>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>` and `<tfoot>` tags are allowed inside `<table>` element. Thus, `<form>` should wrap entire `<table>`

Comment: just tried adding the table, producing wrong output, can you see where its wrong? http://gyazo.com/3630123d3be2c6962d658a7231c932d2 thanks, having problem getting correct table

Comment: @cbaker can you put the code somewhere from where i can use it..?

And put form tag outside of table and not inside see my above code

Comment: I don't know of anywhere to edit like you are asking :( current code: http://gyazo.com/8e33ca69396d0a9138a22ae08680ae09  and the output looks like: http://gyazo.com/cfd6b1c7e393a284fde82e982dcfc62b (the names should be in the drop down)

Comment: add the echo <select> after <td> and close it before </td>

Comment: like this: http://gyazo.com/e7eeb3105cd9d2e05c421467951fbf4c  something wrong again - its output looks like this: http://gyazo.com/6f947fb9fe75e7c60a8a579cc7f9da8b !

Comment: @YashThakur can you spot the problem from that link?

Comment: come on skype yash.thakur97 or yashthakur.indies

Answer (score 1):

This should work i did not try as i dont have the database

```
        //Query to display all events                                                  
                if ($event_result = $con->query("SELECT Event.Name FROM event")) {                     
                        echo "<form method =\"POST\" action=\"save.php\"> ";
                                echo '<table>';
                                        echo '<tr>';
                                        echo '<td>';
                                                while ($row = $event_result->fetch_assoc()) {                          

                                                        echo $row['Name']. ' ';
                                        echo '</td>';          

                                                if ($student_result = $con->query("SELECT Student.Form, Teacher.Form, Student.Forename, Student.Surname, Student_ID " .
                                                        "FROM Student, Teacher " .
                                                                "WHERE Student.Form = Teacher.Form AND Teacher.Username = '" . $_SESSION['Username'] . "'")) {


                                                        if ($student_result->num_rows) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

                                                                echo '<td>';
                                                                echo "<select name ='". $row['Name']."'>";     

                                                                        while ($row1 = $student_result->fetch_assoc()) {


                                                                        echo "<option value ='" . $row1['Student_ID'] . "'>" . $row1['Forename'] . ' ' . $row1['Surname'] . "</option>";       

                                                                }              

                                                                echo "</select> <br />";
                                                                echo '</td>';          
                                                                echo '</tr>';                                                                          
                                                        }                                                                                                                                      
                                                }
                                        }
                                        echo '</table>';                                               
                                        echo '<input type="submit" value ="Submit">';
                                        echo '<input type="reset" value ="Reset">';

                                        echo '<input type="button" value = "Add student" onclick="location.href=\'http://localhost/sportsday/addstudent.php\'">';
                                        echo '<input type="button" value = "Delete student">';                                         
                        echo "</form>";

                        }





?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly write in css

```
form {
  ⋮ declare css
}
```

or give name to form

```
form[name="value"]{
    ⋮ declare css
}
```

or add any class or id on form

```
#formid{
    ⋮ declare css
}

.formclass{
       ⋮ declare css
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First , check your database...
May be there is Another Issue not related to Tabular Output.

So , First remove Table Tag..and check whether its working ?

Then try in HTML TABLE TAG

Otherwise give me sample database .sql File and complete PHP code in google drive or on shared drive.

So that I can check and identify where is problem ?